# Includegraphics doesn't work on Linux. Not even when I put the exact path

Tags: includegraphics

I have

```
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{/home/user/thesis/template-latex_thesis/template_thesis/chapters/picture}
```

and that is exactly where it is located. Does someone have an idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: there will be an error message in the log if it didn't work. Unless you show that we can't really help

Comment: Often relative paths work more robustly than exact paths, and also including the file extension can help. So I would try putting the file in the same directory as the `.tex` document and using `\includegraphics{picture.eps}` to see if that works.

Comment: Did you use the `graphicx` or `graphics` packages?